# Bootstrap, datatable, AJAX, search

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I understand that there is AJAX: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html
and there is searching: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

but I have no idea how to combine the two. Exactly, when .search, which column does it search by? And what if I want to connect the conditions with ADD ?

Comment: this is what in the example you see. Ajax do works, but how to make it work with multiple column search?

Answer (score 0):

In server-side processing mode, jQuery DataTables sends the following parameters among many others:

> `search[value]`   Global search value. To be applied to all columns which have searchable as true.
>
> `columns[i][search][value]`   Search value to apply to this specific column.

So in the request there would be global search value and search value for each individual column ( `columns[0][search][value]`, `columns[1][search][value]`, etc.).

You would need to construct your database query to handle both parameters and return result in the appropriate format.

If you're using PHP, there is [`ssp.class.php`](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php) that does it for you. Otherwise you may want to search for a library for your language of choice or write your own from scratch.

See [server-side processing](http://datatables.net/manual/server-side) for more information.